# How do I install the certificate in firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy, ssl, certificate, mitmproxy

So I've been trying to get this program working: [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). The program is a proxy tool to play around with HTTP and HTTPS traffic. For it to work with a browser correctly you need to configure Firefox with something call a certificate.

I've been having trouble with the certificates. The one it gives for Firefox asks for a password when I try to import it: [Screenshot of Firefox password window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qvN.png) The site doesn't give me the password for the certificate import file so I'm not sure if I'm importing it wrong or theres just something wrong with the file. If anyone knows anything about how to get this to work please help me out!!!

Comment: Have you tried a blank password?

Comment: You can also try to install it manually "certutil.exe -importpfx Root mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12" or use the PEM file that I believe it is given to you too

Comment: @user1156544 - Not for Firefox on Windows.  It uses it's own trust-anchor store.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596121/mitmproxy-certificate-prompting-for-the-password

Comment: @user1156544 I've tried a blank password and the command line code and they both just don't work.

Comment: Can you share the certificates you got from mitmproxy and explain a bit how/where did you get them from?

Comment: @user1156544 Sure! Okay, so the certificate it gave for the windows platform is [here](http://mitm.it/cert/p12). I got this from their site that generates the cert.

Comment: I cannot access that URL. It says forbidden

Comment: @user1156544 to use it you need to have the proxy running.

Comment: Are you not attempting to add your own certificate to the Firefox certificate store?  If that isn't the case what certificate are you trying to add to the Firefox certificate store?  What OS are you using?  Do other browsers give you the same problem?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  The reason comments should be not submitted is the exact reason, I am not asking for this information, that is contained within a comment instead of your question body,

Comment: @garethTheRed - You can configure Firefox to use the Windows certificate store easily enough.

Comment: @Ramhound - but very unlikely in this scenario when the OP had to _"configure Firefox with something call a certificate._ (sic).

Comment: They would have to install the certificate no matter what browser they used.